# CSS: i don't want containers to move below each other

Tags: html, css, user-interface, containers

It draws like this that IS what i expect:

```
 ______________________topofpage __________________________
 anything.gif                            rightbox2 rightbox
 __________________________________________________________
```

But if the screen is small or browser is resized for a small enough size that's what happens:

```
 ______topofpage _____
 anything.gif rightbox    
 _____________________                                       
 rightbox2
```

If it is even smaller, that's what happens:

```
 ____topofpage ___
   rightbox    
 _________________                                       
 anything.gif 
 rightbox2
```

And that's what i want to happen at worst if screen/browser size is smaller than the contents:

```
  __________topofpage____________

  anything.gif rightbox2 rightbox   
  _______________________________
```

Comment: What is your exact question? Do you want the ----- stay around the elements?

Comment: On the smallest screen/browser size it should look like the last visual example i gave, where `anything.gif`, `box2` and `box` stay side by side inside of `topofpage`

Comment: post all the related code, from the code you showed we can see like this only http://jsfiddle.net/saLvhrLy/

Comment: You should be using media queries something like this: @media screen and (max-width: 300px){ }

Comment: Here's a hint, mimic the `table cells` by using `display: table` on your parent div. That should keep your child elements on one row.

Comment: i want to exactly mimic a table, but it is not working :-( no suggestion here is working...maybe i should make an actual table inside topofpage

Answer (score 0):

Give width in-terms of % instead of 'px'.

Comment: Give width in % for all 3 elements and use display: inline-block; float:left for the first element and display: inline-block to other 2 elements

Answer (score 0):

*If you want fixed position, not very clear what you have asked:-*

```
#ContainerAFixed
{
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  margin-left: -200px; /*half the width*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to use are media queries where when the browser gets below a certain size you force the container `#topofpage` to be a defined width. That way you can prevent the wrapping.

Also if you put `#rightbox` and `#rightbox2` in their own containing div float that right, and float the img left (and make it `display:block` ) and then in your media query below a certain breakpoint give it a specific width, it won't wrap.

```
<div id="topofpage">
   <img src="anything.gif"> 
   <div id="rightContainer">
     <div id="rightbox">...</div>  
     <div id="rightbox2">...</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

ie

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #topofpage{
        width: 500px;
    }
    #rightContainer {
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle to let me know what you are having trouble with.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k921u0ov/ Looks just like i want with all elements side by side until you start making the browser screen smaller. I want to keep the elments side by side no matter how small is the screen, if it does not fit the screen it should still stay side by side.

Comment: Hi.Have updated your fiddle showing one option. Set a min width for the container. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/claytonF/k921u0ov/1/)